# How to install a matlab toolbox directly downloaded from mathworks

Tags: installation, matlab

I have downloaded this tool box PSOt from mathworks: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7506-particle-swarm-optimization-toolbox

but I cannot install it into my existing matlab (R2009b 7.9.0). The steps that I performed ar as follows:

```
File -> Set path -> Add with subfolders 
[[choose the parent directory of the tollbox]]
save
```

but the toolbox didnot appear in my existing matlab toolbox. This is my first time installing an additional toolbox, so I don't know if I need anything else to do so.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I guess it doesn't appear in the matlab toolbar by default. but still you can use the added toolbox by calling the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that a toolbox, is not much more than several individual functions.

To use these, you need to do the same as when you want to use other functions.

1. Download the functions
2. Make sure the functions are stored somewhere on your MATLAB `path`
3. Test whether they can be found

In this case the test could be done by something like:

```
edit foxhole
```

If you do not succeed, please give specific information on where it goes wrong, show the location of the file and show your path.